# Linker flag positions in CMake 3.5

Tags: python, c++, cmake

I have a pretty strange question: how do I make CMake 3.5  put the linker flags AFTER the files? 
I am trying to compile a C++ which calls up a Python script. I have these two lines in my CMakeList.cpp :

```
add_executable           (Python_trivium PyCall.cpp) 
set_target_properties (Python_trivium PROPERTIES  COMPILE_FLAGS "${PYTHON_CFLAGS}" Python_trivium PRIVATE "${PYTHON_LDFLAGS}")
```

This generates a Linking error. With "make VERBOSE=1" I can see that the linker command is as follows:

```
/usr/bin/c++     -L/usr/lib/python2.7/config-x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib -lpython2.7 -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm  -Xlinker -export-dynamic -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions CMakeFiles/Python_trivium.dir/PyCall.cpp.o  -o Python_trivium
```

Where the flags are BEFORE the files. I get a "undefined reference" error for each command from Python.h, such as

```
/home/portolan/emanuele/MAST_project/pyhelper.hpp:12: undefined reference to `Py_Initialize'
```

If I invert and put the flags AFTER the files everything works:

```
/usr/bin/c++   CMakeFiles/Python_trivium.dir/PyCall.cpp.o  -o Python_trivium   -L/usr/lib/python2.7/config-x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib -lpython2.7 -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm  -Xlinker -export-dynamic -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions
```

Is there a way to ask CMake to format the linker command line this way?

Thanks,
Michele

Comment: Your `set_target_properties` call looks malformed. The `PRIVATE` attribute makes no sense in this function, and you list the target `Python_trivium` twice. Are you sure this is the code you are using?

Answer (score 2):

I discovered that my error was in trying to do it manually. CMake can do it better for me:

```
find_package(PythonLibs REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})
message("PYTHONLIBS_VERSION_STRING: ${PYTHONLIBS_VERSION_STRING}")
```

Unfortunately it finds 3.5, while I would need 2.7....

Comment: You can set the [`Python_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/module/FindPythonLibs.html) variable before calling `find_package()` to tell CMake to look for a specific version. You can also use `PYTHON_LIBRARY` and `PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR` to point to a specific Python installation.

Comment: For `cmake >=3.12`, I would recommend using: `find_package(Python 2.7 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Development)` instead. And then use the target: `Python::Python`